# cache in visual studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008

Is there some sort of a cache in visual studio 2008? Because when I remove the code that I do not want, it still shows the same output over and over again.
I don't know if I'm still making changes or not. 
Or is a virus making this one. Even if I remove the event which shows the output, I still see the output, and yes even if it looks like this, it still shows an output:

```
Public Class Form2


End Class
```

As you can see its totally empty. Is there some sort of invisible code in visual studio that's doing the magic?Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no special cache.

Try this to confirm you are running the last code:
From "Build" menu, select "Clean Solution".
Then go to "Build" menu again, select "Rebuild Solution" this time.

This is probably some error preventing the build, and not shown correctly in errors window.

Also, if few cases, VS might be locking some files, restarting VS typically solves this.